# Create an Exposed Filter for Integer Values Using Drop Downs

Tags: forms, views

I'm creating a real estate search, and I'm wondering how I might be able to use the Views module to find properties based on their rent per month using a "Min" and "Max" drop downs as opposed to just using text fields.

Essentially, I would like a filter to appear as "Min" drop down box with arbitrary numbers ($100, $200, $300......$10000) and a "Max" drop down with the same values.

Is this possible with any current modules? If not, is it possible through `hook_form_alter()`? If so, can someone point me in the direction of how to get acquainted with working with forms in greater detail?

Comment: This fiddle should be of help, it's for selects, but it's easily adaptable to drive a textfield instead: http://jsfiddle.net/aLyM8/17/

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can do it with form alter hooks. [Here](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/change-views-exposed-filter-form-select-element-list-checkboxes-481.html) is an example. The form id will be:

```
views_exposed_form_<view_name>_<view_type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.
It has exactly what you need.